# MFC application: animating graphics cause program to not respond

Tags: c++, graphics, windows-7, mfc

I am currently trying to create an MFC program that displays a sort of animation involving objects with their locations graphically translated to positions on a small board as rectangles, ellipses, etc. This is a 32-bit program.

The idea I have is to make it so that when a user presses a button, he sees a simulation at a specific rate of time. However, the code I have makes it so that it only runs whenever someone constantly taps a button to advance the simulation.

When I do the same thing with another button, the graphics animate smoothly, generally. However, a (Not Responding) prompt on my window screen eventually shows up in Windows 7 (at a non-specific time), causing the graphics to freeze until the simulation is finished.

How do I prevent the graphics window from freezing?

Relevant code:

```
void Csmart_parking_guiDlg::OnPaint()
{
    if (IsIconic())
    {
        CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

        SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(dc.GetSafeHdc()), 0);

        // Center icon in client rectangle
        int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
        int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
        CRect rect;
        GetClientRect(&rect);
        int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
        int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;

        // Draw the icon
        dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);
    }
    else
    {
        CDialogEx::OnPaint();
    }
    DrawGrid();
}


void Csmart_parking_guiDlg::DrawGrid() {
    CRect gridBase;
    gridDrawSurface->GetWindowRect(&gridBase);
    this->ScreenToClient(&gridBase);
    CPoint bottomRight = gridBase.TopLeft();
    int rectSize = 400;
    bottomRight += CPoint(rectSize, rectSize);
    gridBase.BottomRight() = bottomRight;
    gridBase.NormalizeRect();
    gridDraw->Rectangle(gridBase);
    int baseRectWidth = gridBase.Width();
    int baseRectHeight = gridBase.Height();
    double proportion = (baseRectWidth / world->getGridSize());
    // Draw destinations. Set boolean to check if all are drawn yet
        CBrush brushDest(RGB(165, 42, 42));
        gridBrush = gridDraw->SelectObject(&brushDest);
        CPen penBlack;
        penBlack.CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(0, 0, 0));
        gridPen = gridDraw->SelectObject(&penBlack);
        vector <Location> destLoc = world->getDestLocations();
        int xCenter;
        int yCenter;
        for (size_t ii = 0; ii < destLoc.size(); ii++) { // draw brown circle
            xCenter = (int)round(gridBase.TopLeft().x + destLoc[ii].x*proportion);
            yCenter = (int)round(gridBase.TopLeft().y + destLoc[ii].y*proportion);
            gridDraw->Rectangle(xCenter - 4, yCenter-4, xCenter+4, yCenter+4);
        }
        gridDraw->SelectObject(gridBrush);
        destDrawn = true;
    // Draw lots.
        CBrush brushLot(RGB(35, 62, 148));
        gridDraw->SetTextColor(RGB(35, 62, 148));
        // gridDraw->SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);
        gridBrush = gridDraw->SelectObject(&brushLot);
        vector<Location> lotLoc = world->getLotLocations();
        vector<int> lotSpots;
        vector<Lot *> allLots = world->getAllLots();
        for (size_t ii = 0; ii < allLots.size(); ii++) {
            lotSpots.push_back(allLots[ii]->getOpenSpots());
        }
        for (size_t ii = 0; ii < lotLoc.size(); ii++) { // draw blue circle and number
            xCenter = (int)round(gridBase.TopLeft().x + lotLoc[ii].x*proportion);
            yCenter = (int)round(gridBase.TopLeft().y + lotLoc[ii].y*proportion);
            gridDraw->Ellipse(xCenter-3, yCenter-3, xCenter+3, yCenter+3);
            CString echoNum;
            echoNum.Format(_T("%d"), lotSpots[ii]);
            gridDraw->TextOutW(xCenter + 4, yCenter + 1, echoNum);
        }
        lotDrawn = true;
        gridDraw->SelectObject(gridBrush);
        gridDraw->SelectObject(gridPen);
    // Draw drivers
    vector<Location> driverLoc = world->getDriverLocations(); // get all drivers currently visible on screen
    for (size_t ii = 0; ii < driverLoc.size(); ii++) { // draw red dot
        xCenter = (int)round(gridBase.TopLeft().x + driverLoc[ii].x*proportion);
        yCenter = (int)round(gridBase.TopLeft().y + driverLoc[ii].y*proportion);
        gridDraw->Rectangle(xCenter - 1, yCenter - 1, xCenter + 1, yCenter + 1);
    }
}

void Csmart_parking_guiDlg::OnBnClickedBSimend() // On clicking, simulation jumps to the very end.
{
    while (!world->simulationOver[world->getCurrentIteration()]) {
        run_simulation(*world);
        m_TimeDisplay = world->getTime(); // double
        m_EchoTime.Format(_T("Time: %g"), m_TimeDisplay);
        if (!world->simulationOver[world->getCurrentIteration()]) oss << world->getCurrentEvent();
        CString c_status(oss.str().c_str());
        m_EchoStatus = c_status;
        UpdateData(FALSE);
        OnPaint();
        GetDlgItem(IDC_ST_STATUS)->RedrawWindow();
        pEdit->LineScroll(pEdit->GetLineCount());
        // theApp.PumpMessage(); // this works but it makes it way too slow
        // Sleep(50); // program stops responding at times with a sleep message
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can (and should) get rid of the while loop and just call SetTimer there to start the simulation. Then perform one step of the simulation each time your WM_TIMER message handler is called. You should never call OnPaint yourself. Your timer can call Invalidate to cause Windows to call OnPaint.

Answer (score 1):

Your app is a message handling app, like most windows interactive apps.

This means it needs to process messages, and you should not spend too much time processing each message.

So use messages.

Send a message at yourself asynchronously to advance the simulation.  In that message handler, check if you should stop.  If you should stop, stop.  If not, simulate time advancing (possibly using the current time), draw the next frame, and send a message to yourself asynchronously to draw the next frame.

This allows other messages (like mouse movements) to be processed.

You could even support a "cancel animation" button this way by having a button that sets the "stop the animation" flag, and check it in your "advance animation" message handler.

The annoying part is that you have to save all of your state between each message handler, instead of just using local variables.  If you have access to MSVC2015, I believe they have coroutines that will let you write a function with suspensions and resumes so it reads like your C++ function.

This goes in `OnBnClickedBSimend`.  Have it send a message to itself to draw a frame.  Write a frame-draw-message-handler, hook it up.  Use the existing body of `OnBnClickedBSimend`, replacing `while` with `if`, and at the end of it send another message to yourself to draw another frame.

Optionally, you can do a few loops (with a timer, ie no more than 0.05 seconds spent drawing frames) of updates, then throw another message at yourself to let the rest of the app process messages.

There are other approaches, but this is a simple one.  [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj569217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the best practices for a Direct2d app with multiple threads accessing one object: have your canvas be a Direct2d surface, and spawn a thread to update it.

Comment: Lots and lots and lots of uninformed opinion, I'm afraid. `WM_MOUSEMOVE` messages are *low priority messages*. These messages are only generated, when there are no other messages in the message queue. Posting a message (I assume that's what you mean by *"sending asynchronously"*) makes sure, that no `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message is generated. The remainder of this answer is equally misleading. I'm afraid, I'll have to cast a vote here.